# Thinkpad Edge E535 freezing

Tags: freeze, crash, shutdown, thinkpad

I bought a new Thinkpad Edge E535. has 4GB of RAM and specs at the bottom of the post. It freezes randomly in Windows Explorer and sometimes it has problems shutting down. When I shut down the screen turns off when its about to turn off and the system stays on. Does not respond to anything except hard off via the power button. During these freezes Control Alt Delete does not work. I will add more RAM soon.

```
AMD A-Series A10-4600M
Windows 7 Home Premium (64 bit)
15.6" W HD (1366x768) AntiGlare, Midnight Black
Integrated AMD Radeon HD Graphics
4 GB DDR3 - 1600MHz (1 DIMM)
Keyboard with Number Pad - US English
720p HD Camera
500GB Hard Disk Drive, 7200rpm
DVD Recordable
6 cell Li-Ion Battery 48WH - 75+
65W AC Adapter - US (2pin)
ThinkPad b/g/n Wireless & Bluetooth 4.0 (1x1 BGN & BT 4.0)
```

Comment: Did you install the drivers for your APU (normal Catalyst drivers) ?

Comment: Yes I did. AMD Catalyst mobility drivers were used from AMD's site.

Comment: If it's a brand new machine I recommend you let Lenovo take a look at it and get it replaced if it's a hardware issue.

Comment: OK. Will think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Got in for warranty service at a local shop. Turned out to be the HDD. Works great now.